# MYSQL group concat limit separator

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query and it works fine for me. It shows me the descriptions up to a maximum of 10 separated by commas.
But I would like that if there were more than 10, at the end I would put ', ...' to indicate that there are more fields that have been hidden.

Is there any way to perform this action?

Thanks in advice

```
SELECT ad.domain, GROUP_CONCAT(g.description LIMIT 10)
FROM allowed_domains ad, allowed_domain_groups adg, groups g
WHERE ad.id = adg.id_allowed_domain
AND adg.id_group = g.id
GROUP BY ad.id
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(g.description) DESC
```

Comment: I know mariadb supports limit in group_concat but I don't think mysql does , Have you tagged correctly select version() and publish result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an IF statement like this:

```
SELECT
    ad.domain,
    IF(COUNT(*) > 10, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(g.description LIMIT 10), '...'), GROUP_CONCAT(g.description LIMIT 10)) 
FROM
    allowed_domains ad,
    allowed_domain_groups adg,
    groups g 
WHERE
    ad.id = adg.id_allowed_domain 
    AND adg.id_group = g.id 
GROUP BY
    ad.id 
ORDER BY
    GROUP_CONCAT(g.description) DESC
```